# Values Across Different Rows - combine them into 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have the following results across a table, and what I need to get is the Frequency column down onto the appropriate rows, so the NULL values in the Frequency column are replaced with the appropriate value. Noting the CustomerCode different values.

Anyone know how this could be done, and in doing so removing the Frequency row that doesn't have the Type and TypeAmount?

```
CustomerCode    Frequency   Type    TypeAmount
C12345          Monthly     NULL    NULL
C12345          NULL        A1      5.00
C12345          NULL        A2      20.00
C12345          Fortnightly NULL    NULL
C12345          NULL        A1      5.00
C12345          NULL        A2      20.00
C56789          Fortnightly NULL    NULL
C56789          NULL        A1      50.00
```

Desired Output

```
CustomerCode    Frequency   Type    TypeAmount
C12345          Monthly     A1      5.00
C12345          Monthly     A2      20.00
C12345          Fortnightly A1      5.00
C12345          Fortnightly A2      20.00
C56789          Fortnightly A1      50.00
```

Sample Data

```
Create Table #Data
(
    CustomerCode varchar(50),
    Frequency varchar(50) NULL,
    Type varchar(50) NULL,
    TypeAmount money NULL
)

insert into #Data
(
    CustomerCode,
    Frequency,
    Type,
    TypeAmount 
)
select
    'C12345',
    'Monthly',
    NULL,
    NULL
union all
select
    'C12345',
    NULL,
    'A1',
    '5.00'
union all
select
    'C12345',
    NULL,
    'A2',
    '20.00'
union all
select
    'C12345',
    'Fornightly',
    NULL,
    NULL
union all
select
    'C12345',
    NULL,
    'A1',
    '5.00'
union all
select
    'C12345',
    NULL,
    'A2',
    '20.00'
union all
select
    'C56789',
    'Fornightly',
    NULL,
    NULL
union all
select
    'C56789',
    NULL,
    'A1',
    '50.00'

select * from #Data
```

Comment: Desired output would be helpful.

Comment: @Arun - sure, done

Comment: I have posted an answer. Check it out!

Comment: Does this work?

Comment: Thanks @arun - I'm testing at the moment, it's still running after 8 mins against the real data.

Comment: Without another column to order by, how do you know what is associated with what? This is a standard gaps-and-islands problem, but it cannot be solved without a definitive ordering

Comment: @Charlieface - the data is always in the order of the Frequency showing first, and then the rows related underneath. Anything you could propose?

Comment: Sorry that's not an actual order: you have `Monthly` `NULL` `NULL` `Fortnightly` `NULL` `NULL` So the nulls are not grouped together. There is no such thing in SQL as "underneath" (tables have no inherent ordering), you need an *actual* column value to order by. Is there any column such as `Id` or `CreatedDate` that you can use?

Comment: @Charlieface - there isn't an ID or CreatedDate unfortnately.

Comment: Then it's impossible. As I noted on the below answer, if you have no inherent ordering then the result is arbitrary and may get differing results each time. The fact you ran the code even a thousand times and got the same result doesn't mean it won't change in the future. SQL tables have no inherent ordering, you *cannot* rely on them returning in any particular order. They don't necessarily return in the order you insert them in. You need a primary key or some kind of ordering column

Comment: OK, thanks @Charlieface. If I could somehow get some sort of ordering column, I assume I could just change the Order by statement accordingly in the answer below?

Comment: Yes, although there are better answers than this

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface - what I might do then is try and get a ID included, and create a new question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some defined order to your data or else you cannot perform this query. I created an order by inserting your data into a temp table with an identity column for your reference. I'm assuming there is some underlying order defined in your source data. Just swap that out with my surrogate key column [ID]

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Data

Create Table #Data
(
    ID int Identity(1,1),
    CustomerCode varchar(50),
    Frequency varchar(50) NULL,
    Type varchar(50) NULL,
    TypeAmount money NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Data (CustomerCode,Frequency,[Type],TypeAmount )
VALUES ('C12345','Monthly',NULL,NULL)
,('C12345',NULL,'A1','5.00')
,('C12345',NULL,'A2','20.00')
,('C12345','Fornightly',NULL,NULL)
,('C12345',NULL,'A1','5.00')
,('C12345',NULL,'A2','20.00')
,('C56789','Fornightly',NULL,NULL)
,('C56789',NULL,'A1','50.00')

Select *
FROM #Data

SELECT A.ID
    ,B.Frequency
    ,A.Type
    ,A.TypeAmount
from #Data as A
Cross Apply 
(   /*Grab most recent preceding row that has frequency populated*/
    SELECT Top (1) DTA.Frequency
    From #Data AS DTA
    Where A.CustomerCode = DTA.CustomerCode
    AND DTA.ID < A.ID
    AND DTA.Frequency IS NOT NULL
    Order by DTA.ID DESC
) AS B
WHERE A.Frequency IS NULL
```

If performance is an issue, recommend creating an index like so before executing your select:

```
Create Index ix on #Data(CustomerCode,ID) Include (Frequency)
```

Answer (score 1):

`RECURSIVE CTE` should do the trick:

```
With cte AS
(
SELECT customerCode, frequency, type, TypeAmount, rn
FROM 
    (
     SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerCode ORDER BY CustomerCode) AS rn
     FROM #data
    ) AS d
WHERE Frequency IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT d2.customerCode, cte.frequency, d2.type, d2.TypeAmount, d2.rn
From 
     (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CustomerCode ORDER BY CustomerCode) AS rn
      FROM #data
     ) AS d2
INNER JOIN cte
  ON d2.rn=cte.rn+1
  AND d2.CustomerCode=cte.CustomerCode
WHERE d2.Frequency IS NULL
)

SELECT * 
FROM cte 
WHERE Type IS NOT NULL 
  AND TypeAmount IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY CustomerCode, rn;
```

**Result:**

| customerCode | frequency | type | TypeAmount | rn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C12345 | Monthly | A1 | 5.0000 | 2 |
| C12345 | Monthly | A2 | 20.0000 | 3 |
| C12345 | Fornightly | A1 | 5.0000 | 5 |
| C12345 | Fornightly | A2 | 20.0000 | 6 |
| C56789 | Fornightly | A1 | 50.0000 | 2 |

**Query explanation:**

1. Creating a `rownumber` so that we can refer to the previous row to get the `frequency`
2. 1st part of `CTE` will fetch `NON NULL` frequencies and 2nd will fetch `NULL` frequencies
3. Joining both with 1 row ahead to get the respective `Frequency`

See [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=67cc4564d300009c77803e766b9d6293) here

Comment: Thanks Arun, it seems to produce the correct result. However it is very slow when it is run against tens of thousands of records. Any changes you could suggest?

Comment: @Philip, I guess this can't be made faster because we have used JOINS in possible places. However, Creating `ROW_NUMBER` could be done before startin with CTE (so that sub-query will be reduced)

Comment: `PARTITION BY CustomerCode ORDER BY CustomerCode` is completely non-deterministic, and may return different results each time. The fact it worked once or a hundred times doesn't mean it will always work. You *need* another column to order by

Comment: Charlieface is correct, there needs to be defined order on the data. @Arun there is no need for recursion, it introduces unnecessary complexity and performance challenges. Just need a simple CROSS APPLY to look up the last populated frequency value (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte1 as
(select CustomerCode,Frequency,ROW_NUMBER()over( order by 
customercode)rn,Type,TypeAmount from #Data a ),
cte2 as (   select * from cte1 where  Frequency is not null)
select row_number()over(order by 
cte2.rn)sno,cte1.CustomerCode,cte2.Frequency,cte1.Type,cte1.TypeAmount from cte1
inner join cte2 on cte1.CustomerCode=cte2.CustomerCode
where cte1.Type is not null
group by cte1.CustomerCode,cte2.Frequency,cte1.Type,cte1.TypeAmount,cte2.rn
order by 1
```